# HAVING clause not working when adding column (need Check constraint?)

Tags: sql, constraints, having-clause

SQL #1 returns me 163 accts (through the HAVING clause) as it’s giving me accounts that first bought a particular package (package 102) starting in 2013.

Now I want to break down sales by fiscal month in 2013, and when I add [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label] as column, it gives me 406 accounts, and the HAVING clause is now basically not working.  See SQL #2 below.  Any thoughts why adding Fiscal_Month is basically then giving me all accounts that have ever bought that package type?  I read online that a check condition might help but no luck in writing it.

**SQL #1**

```
SELECT 

sum([FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume]) AS [CaseAndGallonVolume],
sum([FactActualDetail].[AdjGrossMarginAmount]) AS [AdjGrossMarginAmount],
left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #]

FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail] 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] 
    ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK] = [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])
LEFT JOIN [Common].[DimDate] [DimDate] 
    ON ([FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK] = [DimDate].[DateSK])

WHERE [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND ([SC] = 04 OR [SC] = 06 OR [SC] = 07) 
  AND (substring([SourceCustomerProductCode],8,3) = 102) 
  AND [Fiscal_Year] IN (2013, 2012)

GROUP BY left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7)

HAVING MIN([Fiscal_Year])=2013
```

**SQL #2**

```
SELECT 

sum([FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume]) AS [CaseAndGallonVolume],
sum([FactActualDetail].[AdjGrossMarginAmount]) AS [AdjGrossMarginAmount],
left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #],
[Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label] AS [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label]

FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail] 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] 
    ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK] = [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])
LEFT JOIN [Common].[DimDate] [DimDate] 
    ON ([FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK] = [DimDate].[DateSK])

WHERE [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND ([SC] = 04 OR [SC] = 06 OR [SC] = 07) 
  AND (substring([SourceCustomerProductCode],8,3) = 102) 
  AND [Fiscal_Year] IN (2013, 2012)

GROUP BY 
  left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7),
  [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label]


HAVING MIN([Fiscal_Year])=2013
```

Comment: Please post data sample representative enough to illustrate your problem or, even better, create `SQL Fiddle` http://sqlfiddle.com for your situation.

Comment: When you say accounts, do you mean the number of records returned by your query, or are you actually counting the individual account numbers?

Comment: I mean distinct count of SourceCustomerProductCode.

Comment: Tried Mark Bannister's and his worked!  Thanks Alexander and sqlfood for your answers as they will give me coding for future reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `having` clause no longer works because each group is only for a single fiscal month for an account, and so therefore you won't be able to tell which accounts have activity in 2012 within groups for 2013. Instead, try using an analytical function over the entire period - like:

```
SELECT sum([CaseAndGallonVolume]) AS [CaseAndGallonVolume],
       sum([AdjGrossMarginAmount]) AS [AdjGrossMarginAmount],
       [Acct #],
       [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label]
FROM (SELECT [FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume],
             [FactActualDetail].[AdjGrossMarginAmount]),
             left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #],
             [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label],
             min([Fiscal_Year]) over (prtition by left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7)) as min_year
      FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail] 
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] 
             ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK] = [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])
      LEFT JOIN [Common].[DimDate] [DimDate] 
             ON ([FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK] = [DimDate].[DateSK])
      WHERE [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND ([SC] = 04 OR [SC] = 06 OR [SC] = 07) 
        AND (substring([SourceCustomerProductCode],8,3) = 102) 
        AND [Fiscal_Year] IN (2013, 2012)
     ) sq
WHERE min_year=2013
GROUP BY 
       [Acct #],
       [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label]
```

Answer (score 0):

We'd need some sample data to really answer this question. But I'm going to guess that the issue is that you're now aggregating by account and month in SQL #2, whereas SQL #1 aggregates at the account level only. And because of your HAVING clause, you're basically filtering to all sales for a customer for 2013, whereas before you were filtering for only customers that had their first sale in 2013.

You should be able to accomplish your logic using a subquery, i.e.

```
SELECT [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label] AS [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label]
    , x.[CaseAndGallonVolume]
    , x.[AdjGrossMarginAmount]
    , x.[Acct #]
FROM (
    SELECT 
    sum([FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume]) AS [CaseAndGallonVolume],
    sum([FactActualDetail].[AdjGrossMarginAmount]) AS [AdjGrossMarginAmount],
    left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #],
    MIN([FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK]) AS [minDeliveryDateSK]
    FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail] 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] 
        ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK] = [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])
    WHERE [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND ([SC] = 04 OR [SC] = 06 OR [SC] = 07) 
      AND (substring([SourceCustomerProductCode],8,3) = 102) 
      AND [Fiscal_Year] IN (2013, 2012)
    GROUP BY left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7)
    HAVING MIN([Fiscal_Year])=2013
) AS x
LEFT JOIN [Common].[DimDate] [DimDate] 
    ON ([x].[minDeliveryDateSK] = [DimDate].[DateSK]);
```

Without actual data, this is just a guess as to what the query would look like, but hopefully it gives you an idea of how to proceed. HTH. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that Fiscal_Year is in [Common].[DimDate] table

```
SELECT sum([FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume]) AS [CaseAndGallonVolume],
       sum([FactActualDetail].[AdjGrossMarginAmount]) AS [AdjGrossMarginAmount],
       left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #],
       [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label] AS [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label]
FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail] 
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] 
    ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK] = [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])
  LEFT JOIN [Common].[DimDate] [DimDate] 
    ON ([FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK] = [DimDate].[DateSK])
WHERE [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND ([SC] = 04 OR [SC] = 06 OR [SC] = 07) 
  AND (substring([SourceCustomerProductCode],8,3) = 102) 
  AND [Fiscal_Year] = 2013 AND EXISTS (
                                       SELECT 1
                                       FROM [Common].[DimDate] AS [DimDate2]  
                                       WHERE [DimDate].[DateSK] = [DimDate2].[DateSK]
                                       HAVING MIN([DimDate2].Fiscal_Year) != 2012
                                       )                                         
GROUP BY 
  left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7),
  [Unique_Fiscal_Month_Label]
```

Simple example what I means on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e392e/2)